# Change $y= (1/2)x +1$ into standard form and get the answer $x-2y=-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the answer to the problem because I can check the answers in the back of the book but when I do the work myself I get 
$$
-\frac{1}{2}x +y= 1
$$
when I attempt to change it into standard. I need a step by step explanation on how the book got 
$$
x-2y=-2.
$$

Comment: You multiply by $2$ and get $2y=x+2$ and so $x - 2y = -2$.

Comment: I did a minor edit, since $1/2x$ could be either $(1/2)x$ or $1/(2x)$. It's clear from context what the correct interpretation should be, but it's a trifle easier if the reader doesn't have to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Multiply both sides of your last equation by $-2$:

$-2 \times (-\frac{1}{2}x + y) = -2 \times 1 \to x - 2y = -2.$

Expecting a step 2?  Sorry to disappoint!

(Note that $2$ is the least common multiple of all of the denominators.  That's the factor that you multiply both sides by.)

Answer (score 0):

For standard form your x-coefficient needs to be positive and all coefficients must be integers, so multiply the entire expression by -2